# How to left align my content in Resume in latex

Tags: cv, resume

```
\begin{rubric}{Education}
\entry*[Final Year Project]%
    \textbf{Description: }
    \par{A web based application for hiring and applying for non-technical help.\\HTML, CSS, Bootstrap4 , javaScript,JQuery for front end development.\linebreak}
    \par Node.js as backend language.
%
\entry*[Software Requirement Specification : Online University Clearance System]%
    \textbf{Description} .\par
     A requirement specification document that has project requirements, \\UML diagrams and prototypes.\\
\textbf{Software used:} Microsoft Word
%
\entry*[Database: Zoo Information Management System]%
    \textbf{Description} .\par
     A database was designed for the management of information of\\ animals, birds, zoo managers, their doctors and food suppliers.\\
\textbf{Software used:} Oracle Database
%
\entry*[ Web development : Online Shopping website]%
    \textbf{Description} .\par
      A website for online shopping by using HTML, CSS, JQuery and\\ asp.net suppliers.\\
\textbf{Software used:} Visual Studio
%
\entry*[ Java: Zoo Information Management System]%
    \textbf{Description} .\par
     An interface was designed for zoo information management system\\ which also has database connected.\\
\textbf{Software used:} Eclipse
%
\entry*[C++ : Bank Management System]%
    \textbf{Description} .\par
     A management system that can create account, modify existing account, withdraw or add money.\\
\textbf{Software used:} Dev
 \end{rubric}
```

I want to align it to left.
Right now it is right aligned.
[image]

Comment: why do you have `\par` everywhere? That's almost never used in documents, just use a blank line.

Comment: you haven't provided a usable example but I assume you have `\raggedleft`  or `\begin{flushright}`  somewhere, replace by `\raggedright` or `\begin{flushleft}`

Comment: i have placed flushleft in the start but it did not work @DavidCarlisle